# Maximum of an expression with four variables

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Assume $0 < p_1 \le p_2\le p_3 \le p_4$. What is the maximum of the following expression?

$$
\frac{\left(p_1+p_4\right)\left(p_2+p_3\right)}{\left(p_1+p_3\right)\left(p_2+p_4\right)}
$$

Is that bounded by a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\left(p_1+p_4\right)\left(p_2+p_3\right)}{\left(p_1+p_3\right)\left(p_2+p_4\right)} = 1 + \frac{\left(p_2-p_1\right)}{\left(p_1+p_3\right)}  \times  \frac{\left(p_4-p_3\right)}{\left(p_2+p_4\right)}  $$  and the right hand side is greater than or equal to $1 + 0  \times 0$ but less than $1 + 1  \times 1$.

The values $(1,n,n,n^2)$ achieve the lower bound when $n=1$ but approach the upper bound when $n$ increases without limit: $n=400$ gives a figure over $1.99$.

Comment: Just for completeness: Thus, the answer to the first question is that the expression has no maximum.

Comment: @joriki,@Henry: You mean, it has no maximum but it is upper bounded by 2, right?

Comment: @Mohsen: Yes. In fact its supremum is $2$. By the way, you don't need to ping Henry when you comment under his answer; the author of a post is automatically notified of any comments under it.

Comment: Thanks joriki, good point :)

Comment: Thanks Henry for your answer, I asked a more general case of the above question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119702/upper-bound-of-an-expressions-with-many-variables Could you please have a look at it.

Comment: @Mohsen: joriki answered it there

Comment: Oh yah, that's compatible with your answer :) thanks!